# Why does PDO::PARAM_LOB cause an Allowed memory size exhausted error?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, yii, large-data

I have been able to find very little information about what goes on under the hood here. I am using the Yii 1.1 framework, but I don't believe that's related to this problem. Basically, I'm using this code to insert large files into my database (hundreds of megabytes).

```
$sql = "
    UPDATE {$this->tableName()}
    SET `$column` = :value
    WHERE `$pkField` = :index
";

// $stream is a resource from fopen()
$command = Yii::app()->getDb()->createCommand($sql);
$command->bindValue(':index', $id);
$command->bindValue(':value', $stream, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

$command->execute()
```

When I run this to insert a large, 200Mb file, I get a memory exhausted error. I thought that binding with `PDO::PARAM_LOB` would stream my file to the database instead of loading the whole thing into memory at once. Clearly I'm wrong :p

How does `PDO::PARAM_LOB` work under the hood, and in terms of memory management? Or am I just doing this wrong? The most I could glean from the docs [was this statement from php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php):

> This example opens up a file and passes the file handle to PDO to insert it as a LOB. PDO will do its best to get the contents of the file up to the database in the most efficient manner possible.

Comment: Check out whether the [emulation mode](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#emulation) is enabled or not. I would make a guess that PARAM_LOB would work as intended only when it is turned off.

Comment: Emulation mode was turned on.  I turned it off, and am getting the same result.

Comment: Well, I am out of ideas. I would suggest to test this behavior using mysqli prepared statement and binding using "b" type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, seems like that's just how it works.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40913

This bug has been open for 13 years.  It converts the stream to a string and submits that in the query, since mysql has no native streaming support.

So I guess I'll try using `fopen()` to load in 5000 bytes or so and update the record in chunks.

UPDATE: [Well spank my nekudotayim, the bug was fixed!](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/4419) But only for SQLite :( Apparently fixing it for MySQL would require some reworking of PDO.

Comment: Did the chunked loading work? Do you just update mutiple times, concatenating abnother chunk of bytes each time? I'm trying to stream in a geometric blob, so I'm not sure the database will allow that to be added partially.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much.  Maybe when I get back to my work computer I can post what I ended up using.  Basically, I use fgets to grab like 20Mb of the file and run UPDATE table SET data = data + $hugeStringOfData WHERE id = 123.  Gotta escape single quotes though, and not totally sure how well it works with binary files yet.